# After calling malloc I get an unexpected size

Tags: c++, size, malloc

I have this code:

```
char* str = (char*)malloc(27);
int num = strlen(str);
```

I have run the program in the debag mode and I have seen that num is equals to 40. why? why not 27?

Comment: In C++ you should use new, not malloc. Also I would suggest using either std::string or std::vector<char> as opposed to a dynamic array.

Comment: Really tempted to -1 for your original title.  Whenever a library function is behaving strangely, your first thought should be "How am I using it wrong?" not "the library is broken".

Comment: If you had looked at the documentation for those two functions the answer would have been obvious.

Answer (score 7):

Because [`malloc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) does not initialize the memory allocated (even it did zeroise it it wouldn't help here) and [`strlen()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) depends upon the existence of a null terminating character. `strlen()` will stop counting *only* when it encounters a null terminating character, in this case it was 13 bytes after the allocated memory (reading somewhere it should not be). `strlen()` does not obtain the `sizeof` an array or the number of bytes allocated from a `malloc()` (or any other dynamically allocating function). For example:

```
char buf[32] = "hello";   /* Implicit null terminating character after 'o'. */
assert(5 == strlen(buf)); /* It does not equal 32. */
```

Comment: Mind you, had he used `calloc` the result of `strlen` would have been 0, which is also not what the OP expected.