# Unexpected size when using malloc()

Tags: c++, malloc, clang, clang++

I wanted to test my knowledge, and wrote a small program, which looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    int* mem1 = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    int* mem2 = (int*) malloc(5 * sizeof(int));

    std::cout << "mem1: " << sizeof(mem1) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "mem2: " << sizeof(mem2) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I get the output:

```
mem1: 8
mem2: 8
```

When I change the values, that `malloc(2 * sizeof(int))` to `malloc(3 * sizeof(int))`, the output also doesn't change.

[This](https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/cstdlib/malloc) is the Tutorial I used, so I am not entirely sure, if this is memory safe, with the conversion to `int*` when calling `malloc`.
I have also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475500/after-calling-malloc-i-get-an-unexpected-size) question, but I don't find it to be very helpful in my case.
Clang++ is the Compiler I used, but I don't think it makes any difference.

My best guess is, that it allocates the same memory, because it doesn't know where the memory ends.

Comment: You are not supposed to use `malloc` in C++ like this. It is currently technically always undefined behavior to use `malloc`ed memory without intervening placement-new and it will certainly break in practice for non-trivial types. You are supposed to use `new` or even better no manual dynamic memory management at all. You should use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: All the library functions that the linked tutorial site mentions, with the exception of `<iostream>`, are *C* library functions inherited into C++. The site is not actually teaching the C++ standard library. I suggest you don't use it to learn C++.

Comment: `sizeof` does not do what you think it does. Did you want [std::size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) maybe? Also, *why* are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?? You'd *never* do this `int* mem1 = (int*) malloc(2 * sizeof(int));` in a sane C++ program. The C-style casts should just go, but even then the rest is just wrong. Look up `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is telling you the compile-time size of the *pointer* (it would report the same value even if you never called `malloc` at all). There is no standards-compliant way to determine the amount of memory allocated by `malloc`; you have to store it side-band if you need to preserve that information.

Answer (score 0):

The `8` bytes that you see is the size of the pointer(`int*`). sizeof() is done at compile time and there's no way for the compiler to know this size at compile time(`malloc` is dynamic memory allocation).

Answer (score 0):

The expression `sizeof(mem1)` will *always* return the same value, no matter the size of the allocated memory block! This is because `mem1` is a *pointer* to the allocated memory, and the size of a pointer does not change (within a given environment, that is).

In your case (presumably, a build on a 64-bit platform) pointers are 8 bytes in length. You could build this for a different platform (say, a 32-bit system) and you *may* get a different size (for example, 4); but, on *that* platform, that size will then *always* be 4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, there are a few problems in this question:

1. In C++ you dynamically allocate memory using the *new* operator. The option of using malloc is for working with c-style APIs, when needed dynamic allocations that will be de-allocated by c-free function. In order to make such an allocation, it is best advised to use std::malloc which you can read about in [this link (cpp reference)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc).
2. The operator sizeof is calculating the size of the *static type*, meaning that it is giving you back the size of integer pointer, which is constant, depending on your CPU architecture.
3. Working with raw pointers in C++ is ill-advised, you should always make sure that for each item dynamically created in memory there is an **owner**, that is the one responsible to delete it when no longer needed. In C++11 and later, this can be achieved by using *smart pointers*, such as std::unique_ptr. In fact, C++ has created a great Idiom for resource management, called RAII ([Resource Allocation Is Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii)), which sets it apart from many other languages.